# It is better to add Videos inside Document libraries or inside Asset libraries, if we want to render them inside modern site pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-page, video, modern-pages, assets

I am working on a sharepoint online team site collection which have publishing features enabled. and our client want to be able to upload some videos and to render them inside modern site pages.
Now i find these 2 main appraochies to handle Videos inside modern pages-

1. to upload the videos inside our document library, then to use the Document Library(Preview) modern web part, to render the videos:-

[image]

2. second approach is to upload the videos inside our asset library, then to use the Embed modern web part, and to define the asset library's thumbnail view url inside the Embed web part setting,, as follow:-

[image]

now on both cases the videos will be rendered inside the modern pages, but not sure what will be the differences? and which appraoch is the recommended one to upload videos? now based on my test, i found that if we click on the Video inside the Doc lib modern web part, then the video will be played automatically (which we are looking for), while if we click on the video inside the embed modern web part, we will get this page and the video will not start automatically:-

[image]

Now based on my previous experience from on-premises SP, that Asset libraries are the normal place to upload videos (espically when we enable publishing features), but based on my above test, seems document libraries will render the videos in a more accurate way, where if users click on the Video it will start playing automatically, unlike the embed + asset library appraoch.
so can anyone adivce on this please?

Answer (score 1):

There is an out of the box O365 video portal which you can use instead of using normal document library or Assets library.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-your-office-365-video-portal-c059465b-eba9-44e1-b8c7-8ff7793ff5da

You can even manage the user channels:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-manage-a-channel-in-office-365-video-1fede4cc-13c0-435a-b585-e7fbf1c83bb2

And embed them easily within sharepoint:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/embed-a-video-from-office-365-video-59e19984-c34e-4be8-889b-f6fa93910581

Comment: Now i did not find an App named Video inside our admin center, the license at our end is "Office 365 Enterprise E3 ".. so not sure if we should have the option to create videos portal? second question.  i do not want to over-complicate the issue, i think what the existing doc library and asset library provide is enough ,, but i was asking about the confusing results we got , when we show the videos inside our modern pages!!